# Where to find this directory '/tmp/contents773511482/deps/0/python/bin for deploying flask python app in cloud foundry?

Tags: python, flask, cloud-foundry

> Where can i find this '/tmp/contents773511482/deps/0/python/bin which tells me to add path following while deploying app in cloud foundry. Is location incorrect for those ?

[image]

```
[ERR] The script flask is installed in '/tmp/contents773511482/deps/0/python/bin' which is not on PATH.
[ERR] Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

I have already added in the env variable following:
[image]

```
requirements.txt :
Pillow==6.2.1
numpy==1.14.1
Keras==2.3.1
Keras_Applications==1.0.7
Keras_Preprocessing==1.0.9
Flask==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.1.2
tensorboard==1.12.2
tensorflow==1.12.0
Jinja2
astor==0.7.1
absl-py==0.7.0
grpcio==1.9.1
gast==0.2.2
MarkupSafe==0.23
Markdown==2.6.8
setuptools==45.0.0
termcolor==1.1.0
pandas==0.25.3
protobuf==3.6.1
wheel==0.33.6
```

and manifest.yaml :

```
---
applications:
- name: NST
  memory: 2GB
  disk_quota: 2GB
  random-route: true
  buildpacks:
    - python_buildpack
  command: python app.py    
  stack: cflinuxfs3
```

Comment: You are not using Windows, you are using Linux, so why would changing Windows environment variables help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ignore it.

Reason being, that path, `/tmp/contents/...` is only valid at build time. At runtime, the path will be different. Plus at runtime the path will be automatically added to PATH, so the warning is not relevant there.

What should probably happen is that the Python buildpack should add the `--no-warn-script-location` flag, but it doesn't so just ignore those messages.

Answer (score 1):

Add the environment variables into your manifest.yaml file.

```
---
applications:
- name: NST
  memory: 2GB
  disk_quota: 2GB
  random-route: true
  buildpacks:
    - python_buildpack
  command: python app.py    
  stack: cflinuxfs3
  env:
    PATH: /tmp/contents773511482/deps/0/python/bin
```

Changing the host Windows environment variable doesn't do anything because the app isn't running on the host, it is running in a container.

Comment: I doubt /tmp/contents773511482 is unchanging though